# eigenvalues lesser than $1$ implies contractive map

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider $(\mathbb R^n,d)$ where $d$ is the Euclidean metric. A map $w:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is said contractive if there exists $0<s<1$ such that for every $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$ we have $d(w(x),w(y))\le sd(x,y)$.

> Given a linear map $F:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ with eigenvalues lesser than $1$, I want to prove that $F$ is contractive.

Note that if we have a basis of eigenvectors for $\mathbb R^n$ then $F$ is contractive. Hence I would like to have a generalization of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general, not even if you have a basis of eigenvectors. E.g. $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $1/2$, but $A$ is not contractive, since $A \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.